# How can I add a HREF attribute to <a> links with jQuery and is href always needed?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<div class="style-switcher"  id="colorChanger">
    <a style="background-color: #FFFFFF;" data-style="arctic" title="Arctic"></a>
    <a style="background-color: #F2F2F2;" data-style="aristo" title="Aristo"></a>
```

I am using this code to allow me to change styles. What I do is that I run the following code to **add click events**:

```
    $('.style-switcher a').retheme({
            baseUrl: '/Content/Themes-jQuery',
            themeName: 'jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css',
            loadingImg: '/Scripts/user/styles/img/loading.gif',
            delay: 500
            }, function () {
                var theme = $(this).attr('href');
                }
            );
```

Originally I had href="#" included in each link. Can you tell me do I always need to have this even if the **link is not really used to go to anywhere**.

If I do require it then is there a way I could add this with jQuery rather than entering in href="#" on every style line?

Comment: if you decide that `href` is needed you might consider replacing `#` with `javascript:void(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [W3C Docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-A):

> The href attribute makes this anchor the source anchor of exactly one link.
>   Authors may also create an A element that specifies no anchors, i.e., that doesn't specify href, name, or id. Values for these attributes may be set at a later time through scripts.

There you have it.  As for how w/ jQuery:

```
$('a').attr('href', '#');
```

...or whatever you want to set it to.

Cheers

Comment: The href is not used for anything. It mentions "may be set at a later time" so if I read that correctly it's not needed for the case where the link does not go anywhere because I have attached a click event. Do you agree on that ?

Comment: The docs sure read that way.  Personally I always include at least a '#' as the href but perhaps I should reconsider.  BUT, if you don't need the link to go anywhere consider using a `<button></button>` instead...styled to look like a link, if that's what you're after.  It's the semantic Web after all!

Comment: Thanks Madbreaks. Maybe a button is the way to go :-)

Answer (score 1):

yes yo should use href attribute to display anchor as styled in css.

```
$(function(){$("a").attr({
    href: "javascript:void(0)"})
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
   $("a").attr({href: "#"})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove normal  behavior by "prevenDefault".

```
$('.style-switcher a').click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       // your javascript here.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute is not required. If you decide to use it you can set it with jQuery using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Depending on the browser, certain visual styles are not applied to the A element without the HREF attribute. This is easily fixed with CSS but worth noting.

Here's how to check the document for all A elements without the HREF attribute and set it:

```
$('a:not([href])').attr('href', '#');
```